# What is the source of 1 Satoshi transactions from suspicious addresses (1Sochi.. for e.g.)

Tags: transactions

I can't link to one on block chain because are never confirmed, one example from my wallet software:

```
6dd2861a4f6d025742f6306588f2929f476e8f3b2d25c1487cc245e0a402675c: Seen by 1 peer. Pending/unconfirmed.
     from 1SochiWwFFySPjQoi2biVftXn8NRPCSQC / 3c462f4626dd2fa8e802a5b476f206e9133a69c0bb47b1454b7c44b385d93a92:0
       to 1HULKKRbsP9TcLZcokZ7XHJL1Bf1a2jH3k 0.00000001 BTC
       to 1P2G2EP3c1PvXcn5ZpmYZvR5KkAdYNeYXb 0.00000001 BTC
       to 13d5SNKqE9Q94osrZNZfzRjUTuyBRJECbT 0.00000001 BTC
       to 1fMS4VF4bZvv9WcU8PPP9VVHto3tyfdan 0.00000001 BTC
```

... etc

Comment: Could you edit down your answer to 2-4 lines?

Comment: yes, I have seen these on an address that I own as well

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see them, not that you have compiled them in this pulpy mass for me to see.

However I do not see what is suspicious about these addresses, nor their various splashings about.

They look like the playful work of some bored young men.